# Every morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ is constant

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand why every morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ is constant.

We can cover $\mathbb{P}^1$ with $U_0=\{[x:y]\mid x\neq 0\}$ and $U_1=\{[x:y]\mid y\neq 0\}$. But I have no idea how to prove this.

I found this problem on page 37 of Gathmann's [algebraic geometry notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/de/alggeom.php)

Comment: Write down what a morphism on $U_0$ can be, and what a morphism on $U_1$ can be, and what it would mean for them to agree on the intersection.

Comment: So a morphism on $U_0$ is believe would be a polynomial f(x/y) and a morphism on $U_1$ would be a polynomial g(y/x). I am not sure why setting them equal leads to the map being constant

Comment: Another approach: in general, for a $k$-scheme $X$, a $k$-morphism $X \to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ is equivalent to an element of $\Gamma(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$.  Now just apply that in the case $X = \mathbb{P}^1_k$.

Comment: @ponchan if $f(t) = g(1/t)$, where both guys are polynomials, what are the degrees of those polys?

Comment: @peterag I'd like to say 0, but I'm not sure why that's true

Comment: Write out $f (x) = a_0 + a_1 x +\cdots + a_n x^n$  and $g(x) = b_0 + b_1 x +\cdots + b_m x^m$. Set $f(t) = g(1/t)$, and compare. (The set $t^k$, with $k\in \mathbb Z$ are linearly independent <somewhere> over the base field).